# Variable is distributed among same components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

[image][image]I create a topic component by iterating over topics variable in meeting-edit Component.

```
 <app-topic *ngFor="let topic of topics"
               [topic]="topic"
    >
    </app-topic>
```

The TS code of Topic Component :

```
  @Input('topic') topic: Topic;
  show = false;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

and Template :

```
<div class="topic">
  <p  style="padding: 10px 0">{{topic.name}}</p>
  <label for="upload-photo" style="cursor: pointer">Fayl</label>
  <input type="file" class="inputFile" id="upload-photo" (click)="this.show = !this.show" >
  <div #content style="height: 200px;width: 200px " *ngIf="show"></div>
</div>
```

As you see by default *show* variable is false. When input element is clicked ,it should toggle show variable which would display #content div. But when clicking the input element of each component strange behavior occurs. Only the the variable show of first topic component is toggled. It is like every topic component uses same variable. Why that happens? please help to solve this. it seems a bug.

Comment: try changing `this.show = !this.show` to `show = !show`.

Comment: I changed. But it did not solve..

Comment: why r u using #content ? what is its utility ?

Comment: I actually dont use content. i just added it here to label the div so you understand which div I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue. It was because of input file type element. 
I just moved `(click)="this.show = !this.show"` to label element and it is resolved. Strange but it worked. I think it is a bug of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `#content`, when `show == true` it searched the input that contains `#content` and show it, and since it takes the first one so your first `div` that shown every single time you click on the input:

```
<div class="topic">
  <p  style="padding: 10px 0">{{topic.name}}</p>
  <label for="upload-photo" style="cursor: pointer">Fayl</label>
  <input type="file" class="inputFile" id="upload-photo" (click)="this.show = !this.show" >
  <div  style="height: 200px;width: 200px " *ngIf="show"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it was not because of that.  
I actually dont use content. i just added it here to label the div so you understand which div I mean. Thanks anyway.